# Confused with UIPickerView font size

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using UIPickerView but in a willing to custom the font size in a row in a more efficient way.

First I have tried `viewForRow:` to create a label by myself, and call `titleForRow:` in it to acquire the text content that need to show. It works, but I'm not sure if it is a proper way.

Then I delete the method `viewForRow:` and tried `attributedTitleForRow:` that successfully changed the text color using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, but failed to set font size using `NSFontAttributeName` by next line. I doubt if there is a constraint mechanism that forbid/autoresize the font size change in UIPickerView? (The UIPickerView actually have a constraint of height combines to 162, 180 or 216 that I can only use `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` to custom it, so I really doubt it has another constraints.)

Now I'm very confused if there is a way modify the font size without implement `viewForRow:`, thanks.

> Okay~~~ Now I'm implementing the `viewForRow:` method.

Comment: your approach is right using attributed title. but you should use custom view as if your content will be of more size compared to width of pickerview and height of row then to adjust size and number of lines you need custom view. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698547/how-can-i-change-text-font-in-picker-in-ios-7

Comment: @RuchishShah thanks. so that means if I just want to set a custom font size using default row height and picker view frame, I still need to implement viewForRow: ?