# Which UI element of iOS is this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: See this image!]

I am trying to incorporate a similar kind of view in an app. So, was wondering if its a tableview or something else?(see attached image) I am very new to learning swift and would greatly appreciate if someone could help me identify how this kind of structure can be made. Just the name of the element to be used would be enough. I will look up the details on Apple Docs.

Comment: Customised UIPickerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a customized [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/) with two components. Just like the default Date Picker in iOS.

These questions should help you in styling the `UIPickerView`:

- [How can I change text font in picker in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698547/how-can-i-change-text-font-in-picker-in-ios-7)
- [Custom UIPickerView with Custom Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426219/custom-uipickerview-with-custom-background-color)

---

For that last question, please take a look at **DShah**' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770401/2246164).

> Addition to Nina's answer, below are some of the good custom Picker view controls which will be good to use in terms of performance and customizable.
>   http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cppickerview
>   http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/afpickerview
>   http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/v8horizontalpickerview (Horizontal PickerView)